# Django: Get the id you just received from forms in views (not yet saved)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views

I know it's just a piece of code but i can't find any reference(beginner)
My question is how do i get the id of `cde = form.save(commit=False)` or how do i get the id from the form before i save it?

Comment: How can there be an ID before you've saved it?

Comment: ID's are only assigned to objects saved in database. So, to get an object's ID, you will have to save it first.

Comment: As others have stated, you don't. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to save class B from models that has a default value whenever a data is inserted in forms (or saved in Class A from what you guys said).
class b's foreign key is referenced to class A's id.
i'm a beginner sorry for the questions

Comment: thank you for the answers, i'll try to use the signals, i really can't understand it but i'll try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get id once the record is saved. You can save the record by passing commit = True. Your code will look like :

```
cde = form.save(commit=True)
```

Comment: I'll try to use signals, It's really hard to understand for me T.T ty though